# React: Data not showing on the browser but it shows on the console

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

Good day, people please help. I'm very new to react just started yesterday, I'm trying to migrate my previous project an Island Catalog website to react using ASP.NETCore API. As of now I've connected ASP.NET and react because data appears at the console as shown in the photo.

[image: Browser sample]

UPDATE: The terminal is giving a warning "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props'. Either include it or remove the dependency array." What to do?

However, when I try to render the data to the browser data does not appear.

Here is my `api.js`:

```
import axios from "axios";
    
const baseUrl = "http://localhost:49449/api/"
          
export default {
        //baseUrl + 'dIsland'
        dIsland(url = baseUrl + 'disland/'){
            return {
                fetchAll : () => axios.get(url),
                fetchById : id => axios.get(url+id),
                create : newRecord => axios.post(url, newRecord),
                update : (id, updateRecord) => axios.put(url+id, updateRecord),
                delete: id => axios.delete(url + id)
            }
        }
     }
```

---

Here is the action `DIsland.js`:

```
import api from "./api";

export const ACTION_TYPES = {
    CREATE : 'CREATE',
    UPDATE:'UPDATE',
    DELETE:'DELETE',
    FETCH_ALL:'FETCH_ALL'
}

export const fetchAll = () => dispatch => {
    api.dIsland().fetchAll()
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            dispatch({
                type: ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_ALL,
                payload: response.data
            }) 
        }
    )
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
// install material UI npm i -s @material-i/core @material-ui/icons
```

---

And here is my component `DIslands`:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../actions/dIsland";
//import api from "../actions/dIslands";
import { Grid, Paper, TableContainer, Table, TableHead, TableRow, TableCell, TableBody, withStyles} from "@material-ui/core";
import DIslandForm from "./DIslandForm";

const DIslands = (props) => {
    
    useEffect(() =>{
        props.fetchAllDIslands()       
    },[])//componentDIdMount

    return(
<Paper>
    <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs ={6}>
            <DIslandForm/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs ={6}>
            List of Islands
            <TableContainer>
                <Table>
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>Region</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>Location</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                      {
                          props.dIslandList.map((record,index)=>{
                              return (<TableRow key={index}>
                                  <TableCell>{record.Name}</TableCell>
                                  <TableCell>{record.Region}</TableCell>
                                  <TableCell>{record.Location}</TableCell>
                              </TableRow>)
                          })
                      }  
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </TableContainer>
           </Grid>       
   </Grid>
        </Paper>
);
    //return ( <div>from Islands</div>);
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>({
        dIslandList: state.dIsland.list
    })

const mapActionToProps = {
       fetchAllDIslands: actions.fetchAll
   }
    
(DIslands));
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionToProps)(DIslands);
```

---

Here is the reducer `dIsland.js`:

```
import {ACTION_TYPES} from "../actions/dIsland";
const initialState = {
    list:[]
}

export const dIsland = (state = initialState, action) => {
    
    switch (action.type) {
        case ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_ALL:
            return {
                //...state
                ...state,
                list:[...action.payload]
            }
               
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: where is rendering function? and your reducer?

Comment: Good day I have updated the code, thank you .

Comment: where is your reducer for list?

Comment: I included the reducer. Sorry I'm still not familiar with react's code structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a simple typo in your case. In your console.log, the data being returned has all the object keys in lowercase (name, region, etc), whereas when you are trying to retrieve the properties in your component, you are using capital for first letter (Name, Region, etc). Simply change it to:

```
{
                          props.dIslandList.map((record,index)=>{
                              return (<TableRow key={index}>
                                  <TableCell>{record.name}</TableCell>
                                  <TableCell>{record.region}</TableCell>
                                  <TableCell>{record.location}</TableCell>
                              </TableRow>)
                          })
                      }
```

and it should work. Everything else seems to be right

Comment: Thank you so much it works. I didn't realize it I based the properties of the components to my database in there all fields start in capital letters.